# Во сколько раз знание длины пароля снижает количество комбинаций для перебора?

Tags: безопасность, брутфорс

Допустим возможная длина пароля от 10 до 64 символов (a-zA-Z0-9), но точно известно что длина пароля составляет ровно 20 символов.

Comment: А зачем оценивать длины более 20, ведь программа перебора даже при неизвестной длине до них вряд ли дойдет, если начнет с более коротких

Comment: Математика ➣Комбинаторика ➣ [Число размещений с повторениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Размещение). Вычисляется как количество символов N в степени мест M. Итого решением будет сумма всех размещений ∑F(M), (где M = {10 ... 64}, F = M ^ N) и поделить на F(20). В общем ответ правильный от @AlexanderZonov

Comment: @Mike Многие популярные менеджеры паролей используют одну и ту же длину для генерации паролей, например 40, 128, 256 бит. Или часто есть ограничение в 20 символов  => имеет смысл атаковать эти длины в первую очередь.

Comment: А какие это менеджеры интересно меряют длину пароля в битах, эта единица измерения слабо применима, когда используется только четверть кодового диапазона байта

Comment: @Mike В KeePass они называются Hex Key - 40/128/256-Bit, в алгоритмах шифрования ключ в битах измеряется, может оттуда пошло.

Comment: И сколько же символов интересно в их "256-bit", только не говорите, что 32, должно быть около 40

Comment: @Mike 40-Bit - 10, 128-Bit - 32, 256-Bit - 64

Comment: 256-bit = 64 символа, господи, 4 бита на байт, т.е. алфавит паролей из 16 символов ... ?

Comment: @Mike https://gist.github.com/anonymous/044097196fe25bf71c90ad897a6cbb23

Comment: Паролем принято называть то, что вводит человек где либо для авторизации и следовательно состоит только из набора допустымих ASCII символов. А то что вы дали это набор двоичных данных в шестнадцетиричном виде и к паролям никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: @Mike Я читал что автоматически сгенерированные пароли наоборот самые надёжные, т.к. не подвержены атаке со словарём и Марковскими фильтрами.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/everydaytools/blog/323864/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Количество вариантов одного символа пароля - это

26 (строчные английские)
+ 26 (заглавные)
+ 10 (цифры), итого 62.

Количество паролей длиной N символов - 62<sup>N</sup>.

Во сколько раз быстрее можно перебрать только пароли длиной 20 символов, чем все длиной от 10 до 64, можно посчитать так (Python):

```
vars_all = 0
for l in range (10, 64+1): vars_all += 62**l
vars_20 = 62**20;
print((vars_all+.0) / vars_20)
```

Получается примерно 7.45240060481e+78, то есть на 79 порядков быстрее.

Answer (score 2):

Полный перебор паролей из 20 символов требует `n^20` вариантов в худшем случае, где n — количество символов в пароле (62 по условию или ~94 для ASCII). Полный перебор всех паролей из 10..20 символов требует `(n^10 + n^11 + ... + n^20)` вариантов... т.е. знание длины пароля ускорит перебор в `(1+1/n+1/n^2+...+1/n^19)≈1+1/n` раз (или на `~1,5%` для 62-х символьного алфавита) в худшем случае. В среднем будет `2/n*100%` или ~3%, что также довольно незначительно....

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант

(число_комбинаций_для_64 - число_комбинаций_для_10)/ число_комбинаций_для_20

Число комбинаций считается так: количество разрешенных знаков которое может использоваться в пароле возводится в степень равную длине пароля

Comment: Почти, только суммировать в числителе надо все комбинации от 0 до 64. Число комбинаций только для 64 не равно числу всех комбинаций от 0 до 64. Ну или проще сразу сложить от 10 до 64.